# Regular Expression inside pharse - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression:

```
jQuery("#SomeId")
```

I'm using

```
jQuery\(\".*?\"\)
```

Actual result:

```
jQuery("#SomeId")
```

Expected result:

```
#SomeId
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var str = 'jQuery("#SomeId")';

var reg = /#(\w+)/;

var ret = reg.exec(str); // ["#SomeId", "SomeId"]
```

If you want result with `#` use `ret[0]`, otherwise `ret[1]`

```
console.log(ret[0]); // #SomeId
console.log(ret[1]); // SomeId
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
jQuery\(\"(.*?)\"\)
```

and `#SomeId` will be in group 1.